# Any foreseeable limitations of using named pipes between PHP and process?

Tags: php, c, linux

I want to write a php file which will pipe commands to system (but also handle stdin so that interactive programs can be used also). I have read that this can't be done in php, so I have instead writen a program in C which sets up 2 fifos (in/out). I have tested it in the following sense:

(open 3 terminals)

Terminal 1: ./program which sets up the pipes
Terminal 2: cat fifo_out
Terminal 3: echo "ls -l" > fifo_in

This will show in terminal 2. I will implement the stdin in the C program shortly.

So from the php file I plan to send commands and pipe back responses (including handling stdin eventually). Are there any 'gotchas' I should know about that would make this unfeasible? (e.g. php not handling named pipes between such programs well or there being time-outs or permissions etc.? any suggestions to avoid such pitfalls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Buffering would be the most obvious, make sure you terminate lines with "\n".

Comment: And you'd also run into problems with concurrency.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that duskwuff?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to run a program with bi-directional IO. The documentation contains a fairly comprehensive example

Comment: Note: I'm not really answering the question that was asked here, but AFAICT, the initial assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Hi can you clarify what was the initial assumption?

Comment: @user1166981: That you can't connect both `stdin` and `stdout` to an external program from PHP. As I said, I'm answering a different (though related) question than the one you asked.